# udp not working with sipp

Tags: linux, sip

I am doing some end to end testing using SIPP on RHEL 4.2. Both my client and server machiens are running RHEL 4.2.

When I try to issue the command :

```
sipp -t tn -sn uac <server_vip> -i <client_ip> -m 10
```

on the client and :

```
sipp -t tn -sn uas -i 0.0.0.0 -m 10
```

on the server, all works well ,ie, TCP SIP works fine on port 5060. However, as soon as I remove the -t tn flag and switch to UDP, the server core dumps and produces something like this :

```
Warning: open file limit > FD_SETSIZE; limiting max. # of open files to FD_SETSIZE = 1024
009fa000-00a0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 54074376   /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
00a0d000-00a0e000 rw-p 00012000 08:02 54074376   /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
00b86000-00bb0000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 51782250   /usr/lib/libpcap.so.0.9.8
00bb0000-00bb1000 rw-p 00029000 08:02 51782250   /usr/lib/libpcap.so.0.9.8
00bb1000-00bb2000 rw-p 00bb1000 00:00 0
00dfb000-00dfd000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 51722595   /lib/libcom_err.so.2.1
00dfd000-00dfe000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 51722595   /lib/libcom_err.so.2.1
023c0000-023e1000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 51722603   /lib/libncurses.so.5.6
023e1000-023e2000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 51722603   /lib/libncurses.so.5.6
077e2000-0787f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 51722596   /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3.3
0787f000-07882000 rw-p 0009c000 08:02 51722596   /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3.3
079ea000-07b21000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 51722598   /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8g
07b21000-07b35000 rw-p 00136000 08:02 51722598   /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8g
07b35000-07b38000 rw-p 07b35000 00:00 0
07b3a000-07b81000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 51722599   /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8g
07b81000-07b85000 rw-p 00046000 08:02 51722599   /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8g
07ccf000-07db6000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 60143853   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
07db6000-07dba000 r--p 000e6000 08:02 60143853   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
07dba000-07dbc000 rw-p 000ea000 08:02 60143853   /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.10
07dbc000-07dc1000 rw-p 07dbc000 00:00 0
07ddc000-07df2000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 54763893   /lib/libtinfo.so.5.6
07df2000-07df5000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 54763893   /lib/libtinfo.so.5.6
08048000-0809c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 50347877   /usr/bin/sipp
0809c000-0809e000 rw-p 00053000 08:02 50347877   /usr/bin/sipp
0809e000-081f3000 rw-p 0809e000 00:00 0
086bf000-086fb000 rw-p 086bf000 00:00 0          [heap]
76cb4000-76cb5000 ---p 76cb4000 00:00 0
76cb5000-776b5000 rw-p 76cb5000 00:00 0
776b5000-776b6000 ---p 776b5000 00:00 0
776b6000-780bc000 rw-p 776b6000 00:00 0
7faba000-7facf000 rw-p 7ffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
                                                                                           Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am running sipp-3.3. I am unsure what to make of this. By the way, my netstat shows that my server is listening to port 5060 for both tcp and udp traffic, so that rules out one problem!

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are more likely to find the necessary expertise on one of the other Stack Exchange sites, like Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are dealing with an opened file descriptors limit, you might want to

```
ulimit -n 4096
```

before starting your *sipp* server/clients.